# Colorizing Text within Rich Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, rich

Im building some trees within Rich. However Im outputting obj repr() and also Python object details that Rich only seems to want to display if I pass the data to the tree branch as a string. i.e.

```
tree = Tree(str(type(root_obj)))
```

My question is this out can i colourize the output of my tree in Rich. For example if I pass a type to the tree without casting it to a string I get:

```
tree = Tree(type(root_obj))
...
rich.errors.NotRenderableError: Unable to render <class 'nornir.core.task.AggregatedResult'>; A str, Segment or object with __rich_console__ method is required
```

But not sure what console method to use here. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can highlight text via a Rich *highlighter*. The ReprHighlighter will highlight the strings produces from most objects. Import it like this:

```
from rich.highlighter import ReprHighlighter
highlighter = ReprHighlighter()
```

Now you can highlight strings in the following way:

```
tree = Tree(highlighter(str(root_obj)))
```

Alternatively, you can use Rich's pretty printing capabilities via the `rich.pretty.Pretty` class:

```
from rich.pretty import Pretty

tree = Tree(Pretty(rich_obj))
```